# Battery reduced by 50%> How to make my battery last longer than windows 7 for HP pavilion g7?

Tags: ati, lubuntu, power-management, hp, battery

I have a HP Pavilion g7-1204sa 17.3 inch Laptop PC AMD Quad-Core A6-3400M Processor, RAM 6GB.

I am attempting to make my laptop to last longer on Lubuntu or Ubuntu OS than windows 7. It currently only lasts about 1 hour and 43 minutes on lubuntu and that's pretty bad as windows 7 can last for 4 hours. I was wondering if it is possible if there are any tools fixes or updates to the kernel/ graphics software to make it last longer.

I have noticed that the fan is working too hard and is heating up when under no stress what so ever. i would also like to know if there are any specific updates, software or ppa's to my computer specs to make the battery last longer. any suggestions or experiences would be helpful,

i am looking for fixes specifically to my laptop or to the specs of my laptop. this is not a duplicate as there are no questions on ask ubuntu that are HP G series .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `tlp`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw 
sudo tlp start 
sudo tlp-stat
```

Comment: may i ask what does this do? is it a tool?

Comment: From https://launchpad.net/~linrunner/+archive/tlp : TLP is a power management tool for Linux. It brings you the benefits of advanced power management without the need to understand every technical detail. Project homepage: http://linrunner.de/tlp

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681